# Oracle database: How to read a BLOB?

Tags: sql, oracle, blob

I'm working with an Oracle database, and I would like to read the contents of a BLOB. How do I do this?

When I do a simple select statement, it merely returns "(BLOB)" (without the quotes). How do I read the actual contents?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/828650/how-do-i-get-textual-contents-from-blob-in-oracle-sql/828834#828834

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get textual contents from BLOB in Oracle SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/828650/how-do-i-get-textual-contents-from-blob-in-oracle-sql)

Comment: I tried the query in that thread and got the following error message: "ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: raw variable length too long
ORA-06512: at line 1
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
*Cause:    
*Action:"

Comment: In Binary Lob (Character LOB) could contain values which are not representable like VARCHAR. In PL\SQL, a VARCHAR variable can contain 32767 byte, pay attention to database charset too.

Comment: Why not use a GUI client that can show the contents of the BLOB columns (assuming you are using SQL*Plus)

Comment: @ktm5124, I am getting the same error in a different issue, and I'm trying to address it here, in case you are interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743084/how-can-i-avoid-raw-variable-length-too-long-errors-in-sql-developer/

Answer (score 11):

You can dump the value in hex using `UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2())`.

```
SELECT b FROM foo;
-- (BLOB)

SELECT UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(b))
FROM foo;
-- 1F8B080087CDC1520003F348CDC9C9D75128CF2FCA49D1E30200D7BBCDFC0E000000
```

This is handy because you this is the same format used for inserting into BLOB columns:

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE foo (
    b BLOB);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES ('1f8b080087cdc1520003f348cdc9c9d75128cf2fca49d1e30200d7bbcdfc0e000000');

DESC foo;
-- Name Null Type 
-- ---- ---- ---- 
-- B        BLOB
```

However, at a certain point (2000 bytes?) the corresponding hex string exceeds Oracle’s maximum string length. If you need to handle that case, you’ll have to combine [How do I get textual contents from BLOB in Oracle SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/828650/how-do-i-get-textual-contents-from-blob-in-oracle-sql) with the [documentation for `DMBS_LOB.SUBSTR`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_lob.htm#ARPLS66748) for a more complicated approach that will allow you to see substrings of the BLOB.

Answer (score 8):

SQL Developer can show the blob as an image (at least it works for jpegs).  In the Data view, double click on the BLOB field to get the "pencil" icon.  Click on the pencil to get a dialog that will allow you to select a "View As Image" checkbox.

Answer (score 3):

If the content is not too large, you can also use

```
SELECT CAST ( <blobfield> AS RAW( <maxFieldLength> ) ) FROM <table>;
```

or

```
SELECT DUMP ( CAST ( <blobfield> AS RAW( <maxFieldLength> ) ) ) FROM <table>;
```

This will show you the HEX values.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the Oracle native data provider rather than the Microsoft driver then you can get at all field types

```
Dim cn As New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection
Dim cm As New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand
Dim dr As Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader
```

The connection string does not require a Provider value so you would use something like:

```
"Data Source=myOracle;UserID=Me;Password=secret"
```

Open the connection:

```
cn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=myOracle;UserID=Me;Password=secret"
cn.Open()
```

Attach the command and set the Sql statement

```
cm.Connection = cn
cm.CommandText = strCommand
```

Set the Fetch size. I use 4000 because it's as big as a varchar can be

```
cm.InitialLONGFetchSize = 4000
```

Start the reader and loop through the records/columns

```
dr = cm.ExecuteReader

Do while dr.read()
    strMyLongString = dr(i)
Loop
```

You can be more specific with the read, eg dr.GetOracleString(i) dr.GetOracleClob(i) etc. if you first identify the data type in the column. If you're reading a LONG datatype then the simple `dr(i)` or `dr.GetOracleString(i)` works fine. The key is to ensure that the InitialLONGFetchSize is big enough for the datatype. Note also that the native driver does not support `CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess` for the data reader but you don't need it and also, the LONG field does not even have to be the last field in the select statement.

Answer (score 0):

What client do you use? .Net, Java, Ruby, SQLPLUS, SQL DEVELOPER? Where did you write that simple select statement?

And why do you want to read the content of the blob, a blob contains binary data so that data is unreadable. You should use a clob instead of a blob if you want to store text instead of binary content.

I suggest that you download SQL DEVELOPER: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html . With SQL DEVELOPER you can see the content.

Comment: Funny. I'm using SQL Developer but it did not show me the content. IT only showed me "(BLOB)"

Comment: It may be related to the SQL Developer version. Seems that the BLOB download / visualization functionality has been added only on latest versions.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested to get the plaintext (body part) from a `BLOB`, you could use the [CTX_DOC package](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CCREF/cdocpkg.htm).

For example, the `CTX_DOC.FILTER` procedure can "generate either a plain text or a HTML version of a document". Be aware that `CTX_DOC.FILTER` requires an index on the `BLOB` column. If you don't want that, you could use the `CTX_DOC.POLICY_FILTER` procedure instead, which doesn't require an index.