# Oracle plsql rtf varchar2 field to plain text format

Tags: oracle, text, plsql, rtf

I need to convert a rich formatted text of a VARCHAR2 field to plain text.

For example:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil Tahoma;}{\f1\fnil\fcharset0 Tahoma;}}
{\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue255;}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\cf1\lang1031\b\f0\fs16 NUMBER_A\cf0\b0\f1 *\cf1\b\protect NUMBER_B\cf0\b0\protect0\f0\par
}
```

should be converted to:

```
NUMBER_A * NUMBER_B
```

I have tried to parse the RTF-string char by char but this isn't a very smart solution.
A PL/SQL utilities method for any RTF-text would be the nicest way.
Is there a native solution? Any ideas how to convert the rtf-text?

Thx for sharing your time and ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently this can be done via Oracle Text - see [this AskTom question](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:25695084847068)

Comment: the only problem is I need a clob instead of a varchar2.

Comment: CLOB? Start here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/828650/how-do-i-get-textual-contents-from-blob-in-oracle-sql

Answer (score 1):

I made it with simple PL/SQL.
[Based on this SQL source](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/821281/Convert-RTF-to-Plain-Text-Revised-Again), but completly rewritten.
(Backslash + Apostrofe confuses code coloring here)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Rtf2Txt
(
    pRtf varchar2
)
return nvarchar2 is
/*
Converts RTF text to TXT format by removing headers, commands, and formatting
*/
vPos1 int;
vPos2 int;
vPos3 int;
vPos4 int;
vTmp int;
vText varchar2(4000);
begin
vText := pRtf;
if vText is null then
    return vText;
end if;

-- Remove outer { and } pair
vPos1 := instr(vText, '{', +1);  -- The first {
vPos2 := instr(vText, '}', -1);  -- The last }
if vPos1 > 0 and vPos2 > 0 then
    vText := substr(vText, vPos1 +1, vPos2 - vPos1 -1);
end if;

-- Remove inner { and } pairs
while 1 = 1 loop
    vPos2 := instr(vText, '}', +1);  -- The first }
    vPos1 := instr(vText, '{', (length(vText) - vPos2) *-1 -1);  -- The last { before the found }
    if vPos1 > 0 and vPos2 > 0 and vPos1 < vPos2 then
        vText := substr(vText, 1, vPos1 -1) || substr(vText, vPos2 +1, length(vText) - vPos2);
    else
        exit;
    end if;
end loop;

-- Cleaning up
vText := replace(vText, '\pard', '');
vText := replace(vText, chr(13), '');
vText := replace(vText, chr(10), '');
vText := replace(vText, '\par', chr(13));
while length(vText) > 0 and substr(vText, 1, 1) IN (' ', CHR(13), CHR(10)) loop
    vText := substr(vText, 2, length(vText) -1);
end loop;
while length(vText) > 0 and substr(vText, length(vText), 1) IN (' ', CHR(13), CHR(10)) loop
    vText := substr(vText, 1, length(vText) -1);
end loop;

-- Remove \ commands and replace \'XX charactercoding
vPos2 := 1;
while 1 = 1 loop
      vPos1 := instr(vText, '\', vPos2);
      if vPos1 = 0 then
          exit;
      end if;
      if substr(vText, vPos1 +1, 1) = '\' then  -- Skip \\ escape sequence, when present
          vPos2 := vPos1 +2;
          continue;
      end if;
      if substr(vText, vPos1 +1, 1) = '''' then  -- Decode \' hex sequence
          vTmp := to_number(substr(vText, vPos1 +2, 2), 'xx');
          vText := substr(vText, 1, vPos1 -1) ||chr(vTmp)|| substr(vText, vPos1 +4, length(vText) - vPos1 -3);
          vPos2 := vPos1 +1;
          continue;
      end if;
      -- Skip \anything sequence
      vPos2 := instr(vText, '\', vPos1 +1);  -- The next \  
      vPos3 := instr(vText, ' ', vPos1 +1);  -- The next ' '
      vPos4 := instr(vText, chr(13), vPos1 +1);  -- The next Enter
      if vPos4 > 0 and vPos4 < vPos3 then
          vPos3 := vPos4;
      end if;
      if vPos2 = 0 and vPos3 = 0 then
          vPos3 := length(vText); 
      end if;
      if vPos2 > 0 and (vPos2 < vPos3 or vPos3 = 0) then
          vText := substr(vText, 1, vPos1 -1) || substr(vText, vPos2, length(vText) - vPos2 +1);
          vPos2 := vPos1;
      end if;
      if vPos3 > 0 and (vPos3 < vPos2  or vPos2 = 0) then
          vText := substr(vText, 1, vPos1 -1) || substr(vText, vPos3 +1, length(vText) - vPos3);
          vPos2 := vPos1;
      end if;
end loop;

return vText;

end;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont'have the repuation to comment CLS's posting, but I would like to 
advise that the line

```
  if vPos1 = 0 then
```

should be changed to

```
  if nvl(vPos1,0)=0 then
```

otherwise with not well formed RTFs the function will be stuck in the while loop forever

Bye
Andreas