# Insert JSON data into oracle BLOB column and select from the BLOB column?

Tags: c#, oracle

I need to INSERT JSON data into the Oracle DB table BLOB column, also I need to SELECT the BLOB column value from the table?

This is my Query to INSERT:

INSERT INTO table_Name values('Test','test1',UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw ({"JSON data"}))

How can I SELECT? Also When inserting the large JSON object it's throwing Error : **"PL/SQL: numeric or value error: raw variable length too long"**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/828650/how-do-i-get-textual-contents-from-blob-in-oracle-sql

Comment: If you can, avoid to store JSON data in one column, create a DB structure instead.

Comment: What is the DB structure? This is my requirement I want to store JSON into DB.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get textual contents from BLOB in Oracle SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/828650/how-do-i-get-textual-contents-from-blob-in-oracle-sql)

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:

create table demo
    ( id           int primary key,
      theBlob      blob
    );

INSERT INTO demo (id) values (1);

update demo set theBlob = utl_raw.cast_to_raw('Hello World') where id = 1;

commit;

select * from demo where id = 1;

select utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(theBlob)) 
from demo 
where ID = '1';
```

Comment: Want to store a large JSON object into a BLOB field, not a string?

Answer (score 0):

That cast_to_raw takes a VARCHAR2 as a parameter and your string is too large.  You need to open the BLOB and write it in pieces.  It's all in the DBMS_LOB package.