# Oracle convert blob to string

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to convert a blob of an oracle db to an readable string.

I have tried some functions, but none of them worked for me.

In the end I tried to convert the string via sql statement like:

```
SELECT CONVERT(CAST(blob as BINARY) USING utf8) as blob FROM tablewithblob
```

Can anyone tell me, what I am doing wrong? The error of the sqldeveloper is "missing right paranthesis. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of BLOB do you have? And what do you mean by "readable string"?

Answer (score 0):

The CONVERT(value USING charset) function is a mysql function, not Oracle

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_convert.asp

Take a look at this instead

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions027.htm

But it looks like DBMS_LOB is a better way to do what you're doing in Oracle. Go check out [How do I get textual contents from BLOB in Oracle SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/828650/how-do-i-get-textual-contents-from-blob-in-oracle-sql)