# Error while executing sql query on database

Tags: sqlite, blob

I'm trying to read BLOB data from `messages` table form WhatsApp database called `msgstore`, I want to get the file names that are transferred. The blob data is stored in `thumb_image` column.

I found this query [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27618946):

```
SELECT dbms_lob.substr(thumb_image)
FROM messages 
WHERE _id = 3;
```

I also tried this query from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/828834):

```
SELECT utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(thumb_image)) 
FROM messages  
WHERE _id = '3;
```

I both cases I keep getting an error thats says:

```
Error while executing sql query on database 'msgstore': near "(" syntax error.
```

I don't understand what's wrong with the query. 
How can I fix this?

Comment: The queries you posted work for Oracle and not SQLite.

Comment: @forpas do you know if there's something similar to that that might work in SQLite?

Comment: Use SQLite's substr(): `substr(thumb_image, 1, 100)`